# Reset checkbox to initial status

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, checkbox

As you may know, Reset buttons in a form can not reset checkboxes to their initial status. How can I make that happen either with javascript or PHP or jquery or ...?
Here is the code I have:

```
<form method="POST">
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="default value" required >
<input type="checkbox" name="group[]" id="checkbox1" value="0" checked>
<input type="checkbox" name="group[]" id="checkbox2" value="1" >
<button type="reset"> Reset </button>
<button type="submit"> Submit </button>
</form>
```

Comment: you could save the inital value in Javascript and then, on the rest buttton click, change the value to the inital one.

Comment: If you won't provide the attributes specifically, that'll reset the checkboxes, if you'll give the default values to any field in the form, it won't be reset. If that can help, if you want these values to be initially filled,  the answers will vary. Please provide full info what you really wanna do..

Comment: Your HTML above works fine for me. It resets the checkbox to the initial status (i.e. checkbox1 is checked and checkbox2 unchecked). Maybe it's a browser issue?

Comment: Can you please explain how your accepted answer is working to reset checkbox to initial status? I believe it will uncheck all checkboxes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Iterate over all your input elements and uncheck the ones which are checked.

```
var allInputs = $( ":input" );

for(var i = 0; i < allInputs.length; i++) {

   if( $( 'input[type="checkbox"]:checked' ) )
      $( this ).prop('checked', false);
}
```

Or as James pointed out, this could be done in one line like this:

```
$( 'input[type="checkbox"]' ).prop('checked', false);
```

Comment: Or just `$( 'input[type="checkbox"]' ).prop('checked', false);` ??

Comment: Yeah can do that instead

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```js
var resetForm = function(){
    $('#form')[0].reset();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" id="form">
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="default value" required >
<input type="checkbox" name="group[]" id="checkbox1" value="0" checked>
<input type="checkbox" name="group[]" id="checkbox2" value="1" >
<button type="reset" onclick="resetForm()"> Reset </button>
<button type="submit"> Submit </button>
</form>
```

Comment: As of jQuery 1.6, modifying the `checked` attr will longer work. You need `.prop('checked',false)`.

Comment: what do you mean after 1.6 `removeAttr` will not work? Btw i am using `3.2.1` latest one

Comment: It will uncheck all the checkboxes.I don't need that.What if a checkbox was initially checked?

Comment: @Mahesh Singh Couhan correct. Here's a codepen: https://codepen.io/jamespoel/pen/MoXwzP

Comment: @Omid updated my answer, now if it was initally checked then it will only reset changed checkboxes

Comment: @James cool!! i don't need to remove any attr from checkbox now, you can take your downvote back now

Comment: @Omid does your accepted answer works for you? i am wondering that it will also uncheck all checked checkboxes instead of resetting the form?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply reset the checked state based on the html attribute

```js
checkbox.checked = !!checkbox.attributes.getNamedItem("checked")
```